# Azure DevOps Visual studio build task fails with "access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator"

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I'm working with a Windows forms application and tried to run the build on Azure devOps.
The nuget tasks run fine and restores the packages.

[image]

But, the Visual studio build task fails with following error.

access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, it appears that you are using the self-hosted agent.

To run the application as Administrator in pipeline, you need to change the agent service account to Administrator.

Generally when we configure the agent as a service, we need to specify an account, which in your scenario should be an Administrator account.